# Proving $ \frac{(n!)^2}{n(2n)!}\sum_{k=0}^n k {n \choose k} ^2=\frac{1}{2} $ by induction

Tags: combinatorics, summation, induction, binomial-coefficients

I'm struggling to prove the following by induction for $n\geq 1$

$$
\frac{(n!)^2}{n(2n)!}\sum_{k=0}^n  k {n \choose k} ^2=\frac{1}{2}
$$

The base case works but trying to prove for $n+1$ is proving difficult, with the algebra getting messy. I think I'm missing something obvious. Trying to prove $m+1$...

\begin{align*}
&=\frac{((m+1)!)^2}{(m+1)(2(m+1))!}\sum_{k=0}^{m+1}  k {m+1 \choose k}^2\\\\
&=\frac{(m+1)^2(m!)^2}{(m+1)(2m+2)(2m+1)(2m)!}\left[m+1+\sum_{k=0}^mk{m+1\choose k}^2\right]\\\\
&=\frac{(m!)^2}{2(2m+1)(2m)!}\left[m+1+\sum_{k=0}^mk{m+1\choose k}^2\right]
\end{align*}

At this point, I'm not sure where to go. Some ideas I have tried are using the fact that

\begin{align*}
{m+1\choose k}&=\frac{m+1}{m+1-k}{m\choose k}
\end{align*}

Or

\begin{align*}
{m+1\choose k}&={m\choose k}+{m\choose k-1}
\end{align*}

But the algebra gets to the point where I feel I am going about it the wrong way. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Induction seems like the hard way.

Comment: Do you see a more elegant way to prove?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove this equation - combinatorics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/809319/prove-this-equation-combinatorics) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7B(n!)%5E2%7D%7Bn(2n)!%7D%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5E%7Bn%7Dk%7Bn%20%5Cchoose%20k%7D%5E2%3D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%24&p=2). Note that multiplying both sides of your expression by $\frac{n(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$ gives $\sum_{k=0}^{n}k{n\choose k}^2=\frac{n(2n)!}{2(n!)^2}$. ...

Comment: (cont.) The RHS of the proposed duplicate is $n\binom{2n-1}{n-1}=\frac{n(2n-1)!}{n!(n-1)!}=\frac{n(2n)(2n-1)!}{n!2(n)(n-1)!}=\frac{n(2n)!}{2(n!)^2}$, i.e., the same as your expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two ways to make the argument without induction.

We know $$k\binom nk^2=k\binom nk\binom n{n-k}$$
and:

$$k\binom nk=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$$

So we have:

$$\begin{align}
\sum k\binom nk ^2&=n\sum_k \binom{n-1}{k-1}\binom n{n-k}\\&=n\binom{2n-1}{n-1}\\&=n\cdot\frac12\binom {2n}{n}\\
&=\frac{n(2n)!}{2(n!)^2}
\end{align}$$

The second equality is a case of the [Vandermonde Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity), and the third is easily shown.

Dividing gives your result.

---

A combinatorial way to think about it is, if you have $n$ men and $n$ women, the value $n\binom{2n}n$ counts the number of ways to pick a committee of $n$ people including a chairperson, while the sum counts the number of such committees with a woman chairperson, which is half of all the committees. (Basically, $k\binom nk^2$ is the number of such committees with $k$ women, and a woman chair.)

This would also give a more general theorem, if you have $n$ men and $m$ women and a committee of size $c$ with one selected as chair you get:

$$\sum_{k=0}^c k\binom mk\binom n{c-k}=\frac{mc}{m+n}\binom{m+n}c=m\binom{m+n-1}{c-1}.$$

Comment: This was really helpful thank you.

Comment: Actually one thing - hoping you can clarify why you can use the Vandermonde Identity when it isn't in the exact form (notably it is k-1 on the bottom, not k, in the first choose function). Also, summing from zero gives a negative number in the bottom of the choose function. I'm sure it is a minor thing I am overlooking.

Comment: Rewrite the sum as:$$\sum_{k}\binom{n-1}{n-k}\binom nk.$$ The $k=0$ case is trivial - $k\binom nk^2$ is zero when $k=0,$ so we can just sum from $1$ to $n.$ Indeed, another way to answer the first part of your question is to skip $k=0$ and let $j=k-1$ and make the sum:$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}j\binom n{n-1-k}$$

Comment: In general, when $k<0$ or $k>n,$ we define $\binom nk=0$ in combinatorial arguments. Most binomial identities remain true.